# Scrolling up while loading more data from server

Tags: android, messaging

I would like to make scrolling up like in facebook/whatsapp messaging applications. While your scrolling up to see the previous message, after loading 20 data and reaches the top, it should download another 20 data from the server seamlessly. How to implement it. Any help please

Comment: Take a look here as well: https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e

Comment: Thanks much. I will try to use this now.